# AngularJS multiple directive elements with template and broadcasting from controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a directive element with a template. The directive template contains a button with an ng-click to call a function in a controller.  When the button is clicked, the controller broadcasts an event and the directives look for the broadcast.  This works great, however, I'm getting an alert for each directive element being used in the app.  I just want the broadcast to be listened by the directive element being used to click the button.

How can I isolate the directive clicks per instance?  I've tried many directive scope avenues but I couldn't find a solution.  And, is this the best solution to use for this purpose?

I created a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/mLnspea0/

```
var app = angular.module('testApp', []);

app.controller('SaveCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.save = function () {
        $scope.$broadcast('saved');
    };
});

app.directive('saveButton', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div class="container"><button ng-click="save()">Save</button></div>',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            scope.$on('saved', function () {
                alert('saved');
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `link` function on your directive is called as soon as you invoke it. In your fiddle, you're invoking it twice. That creates two event listeners for one event, and when you broadcast the event, it's picked up by both listeners, which is where you get the two alerts from.

If I were you, I would move the listener out of the directive and back into your controller. I'd also inject the click action method into the directive rather than forcing the directive to rely on the parent (i.e. controller) $scope. Separation of concerns and all that.

http://jsfiddle.net/zejjxd5u/

```
var app = angular.module('testApp', []);

app.controller('SaveCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.save = function () {
        $scope.$broadcast('saved');
    };

    $scope.$on('saved', function() {
        alert('test');
    });
});

app.directive('saveButton', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div class="container"><button ng-click="save()">Save</button></div>',
        scope: {
            save: '='
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be a little more helpful if you gave an example about the bigger picture here. I don't *think* you're using events / scoping the best way. It probably makes more sense for the save function to be defined in the directive scope instead of the controller scope. And then you'd have access to the element that was clicked.

Then you could emit the event and react to it in your controller

For example:

```
app.directive('saveButton', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div class="container"><button ng-click="save()">Save</button></div>',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            scope.$on('saved', function () {
                alert('saved');
            });

            scope.save = function() {
               console.log(element, "clicked");
               scope.$emit('element-clicked', element);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Seems to me that you've got it backwards. The directive shouldn't need to know how to respond to a save action. What happens if we wanted to reuse the directive in another context that saves data in a different way? Better I think to define a save function in the controller and inject it into the directive.

Comment: Hmm.. I think it depends on the larger use case here and not sure there are large differences between our solutions. He's defining the click event in the directive. In theory the controller knows nothing about how that's being handled. Your solution works as well, but it's only valuable if the controller *needs* to know about what was fired / how to handle the save. I interpreted OP's original question as simply wanting to notify the rest of the app that something happened. I also instinctively would have used '&' style binding, but not sure it matters upon reviewing your fiddle.

Comment: I guess I should have explained why I wanted to use a directive.  I'm using jQuery to show and hide a saved alert.  Right now the jQuery is in the controller and I wanted to move it to a directive.

Comment: @Rob Do you still need more guidance on this?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use an event at all. Why not use a child scope in the directive with its own version of the save function, and call it directly? Then the directive can call the "parent" scope.save() whenever it wants, and run any logic it needs before or after.

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/jxzn6o49/1/

```
app.directive('saveButton', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div class="container"><button ng-click="directiveSave()">Save</button></div>',
        scope: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            scope.directiveSave = function() {
                scope.save();
                alert( 'after-save logic in directive' );
            }
        }
    }
});
```